# How can I use speech recognition in Python on a proxy network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

It works quite well on a proxy free network but whenever I try to run it on a proxy network it gives this error.

```
Could not request results from Google STT; recognition connection failed: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

[Github link for the code](https://github.com/ab-anand/python-works/blob/master/sr.py)

Please help.

Comment: Does your proxy network allow internet access?

Comment: @moritzg Yeah dude.

Comment: @moritzg I add this this line 'os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "http://username:pass@192.168.1.107:3128" ' and it works, but not in this case

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues for the last few days and after a lot of research I found out that sadly Google Speech API currently does not support proxies.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/1061#issuecomment-373478268

Comment: Yeah. I found it accidentally. I gave up on the project. Then after months when I was on a proxy free network and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

After many days working this issue I realized that speech_recognition python package, for desktop aplications (no cloud) is based on urllib that doesn´t support to proxies.

So I had to chage some code lines inside the google package speech recoginition to use requests package (which supports proxies) instead of urllib, such way to make it works:

In your <Home_python>\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition folder open the init.py file and create a new method named def recognize_google_proxy():
Then copy def recognize_google() codes into def recognize_google_proxy().

Now you have two distict objects that makes the same thing.

Next, In the recognize_google_proxy() object,
Change lines like described here:

1. comment comand line bellow with #
   #request = Request(url, data=flac_data, headers={"Content-Type": "audio/x-flac; rate={}".format(audio_data.sample_rate)})

Insert to replace bellow code snipet:

```
import requests
http_proxy  = "http://<your proxy url>:port"
https_proxy = "https://<your proxy url>:port"
proxyDict = {
        "http"  : http_proxy, 
            "https" : https_proxy 
            }
```

2. Comment comand line bellow with #
   #response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)

Insert to replace bellow code snipet:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=flac_data, headers={"Content-Type": "audio/x-flac; rate={}".format(audio_data.sample_rate)},proxies=proxyDict)
```

3. Save init.py
4. 

`import speech_recognition`

That's all.

Now you have available one object without proxy support and using urllib named recognize_google() and another object, with proxy support, using requests named recognize_google_proxy().